# create and open returning two different fd descriptors

Tags: c

```
if((fd = creat(file_name,O_RDWR|S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO)) < 0){
        perror("Create failed!");
        return -1;
}
if((fd = open(file_name,O_CREAT | O_RDWR))< 0){
        perror("Open failed!");
        return -1;
}
write(fd,buff,100);
```

Why do the fd's are different for creat and open, as its opening the same file. 
I want to create , open and write a file.

I should not use the `open(filename,O_CREAT|modes);`

Comment: When you open a file twice, you get two distinct fd's. And actually, you should use `open` with `O_CREAT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `creat` function opens the file after creating it, so from your description, simply calling `creat()` is sufficient for your needs.

To answer your question, it gives you multiple file descriptors because you've performed multiple opens (creat is an open with creation). You can access the same file using both descriptors (and your current location within the file can differ for each descriptor).

Answer (score 1):

Literally creat() function is equivalent to open(pathname, O_RWONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNCATE, mode) so your second open() is redundant. 
You should also keep in mind that the fd is just a handler of your current process. Different handler may point to the same file as we call it "File Sharing". 
Another suggestion is, try

```
if (write(fd, buff, 100) != 100)
    /*Error handling codes*/
```

to make sure the write() works correctly.